# Regex through array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an array that has around 1000 elements, for example:

```
var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "jacob", "dinner": "pizza" }
............];
```

I want to search the `"dinner"`s element of the array with a regex, so it doesn't has to be the exact type. For example, let's say the input is `"piz"`; it should then return all the matching elements as an array. In the example above, it should return:

```
var result = [{ "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
{ "name": "jacob", "dinner": "pizza" }]
```

I know how to search a string using the `.match` function in javascript, but I don't know how to use a similar function in an array. How can I do this?

Comment: You should know, this is not multidimensional array. This is array of objects. Only possible method is coding logic in a loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just for the clarity, it's "A string" not "A piece of string" :P (Unless you mean a part of a string, in which case I guess it's almost correct, if a little confusing and you'd want "A piece of a string")

Comment: .. and is it search is a "contains" pattern instead or a format pattern?.. If the answer is a contains pattern then do not use regex. And how about you trying on your first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [dynamic `RegExp`](http://smyck.net/2006/08/11/javascript-dynamic-regular-expresions/), like this

```js
var search = "piz";
var condition = new RegExp(search);

var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "jacob", "dinner": "pizza" }
];

var result = peoples.filter(function (el) {
  return condition.test(el.dinner);
});

console.log(result);
```